# IVsPackageInstaller package not found on source

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I am installing a nuget package programmatic-ally.  I have 2 nuget sources src1 and src2. MyNugetPackage had some dependencies AAA and BBB. MyNugetPackage is available via src1 and AAA and BBB are available via src2. I am getting error  package  AAA and BBB found on source  src1. How can I make the InstallPackage package install MyNugetPackage from src1 and AAA BBB from src2? I have specifies "All" is source.

```
var componentModel = (IComponentModel)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SComponentModel));

var installerServices = componentModel.GetService<IVsPackageInstallerServices>();
var installer = componentModel.GetService<IVsPackageSourceProvider>();
installer.InstallPackage("All", project, "MyNugetPackage", (Version)null, false);
```

I tried to install from Package Manager Console and got the following error even though AAA.2.0.0 and BBB.2.0.0 are present in the folder c:\users\user\Source\Repos\Testpro\packages:

> Install failed. 
>   Rolling back...
>   Package 'MyNugetPackage.5.6.1.7358 : AAA [2.0.0, ), BBB [2.0.0, )' does not exist in project 'Testpro'
>   Package 'MyNugetPackage.5.6.1.7358 : AAA [2.0.0, ), BBB [2.0.0, )' does not exist in folder 'c:\users\user\Source\Repos\Testpro\packages'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> IVsPackageInstaller package not found on source

To my knowledge, NuGet Visual Studio extension 3.x and above does not have support for the "All" source. This functionality did exist in NuGet 2.x. So the "All" keyword has no special meaning in the 3.x NuGet Visual Studio extension.

To resolve this issue, you can try to "`null`" source instead of "`All`". Using null is the recommended way of installing a package from the user's configured package sources.

See the [similar issue on GitHub](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1944) for some more detailed info.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have same issue in vs2017 and I change All to null but I got still "No latest version found for MyPackage for the given source repositories and resolution context" but same code works on vs2013